# Why isn't grunt-contrib-watch livereload working?

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm struggling to get Grunt's "live reload" ability (as implemented in [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload)) to work in my app. I finally bit the bullet, and tried making a minimal example. Hopefully someone can easily notice what's missing.

**File Structure:**

```
├── Gruntfile.js
├── package.json
├── index.html
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "livereloadTest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3"
  }
}
```

**`Gruntfile.js`**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            src: {
                files: ['*.html'],
                options: { livereload: true }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>

<p>....</p>
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I then run `grunt watch` and nothing *blows up*. However, no browser window opens automatically (should it?).

When I open chrome at `http://localhost:35729/` I recieve this json:

```
{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.0.4"}
```

and trying any other path on that port gives me

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"no such route"}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`http://localhost:35729/` is the URL to the live reload server. It is only used for managing live reload, not serving your actual website.

Typically, one would use [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) to serve static sites with grunt. Then view their site by going to localhost:8000 or wherever you've configured it to reside. But depending on your needs, it could be apache, nginx, etc serving files as well.

There is a `livereload` option on grunt-contrib-connect as well. This only injects the `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` tag into your HTML and nothing else.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I wish the *watch* documentation was a bit clearer that something like this is required...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a really simple way to how you could set that up. Just make sure you have the `grunt-contrib-watch` and `grunt-contrib-connect` plugins installed. This is assuming your Gruntfile.js is in your root directory of your project. also be sure to add `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` just before your closing body tag `</body>` and that you have an `index` file. When you type `grunt server` into terminal go to `http://localhost:9000` and you should be all set up.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },
    css: {
      files: ['css/**/*.css'],
    },
    js: {
      files: ['js/**/*.js'],
    },
    html: {
      files: ['*.html'],
    }
  },
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        base: '.',
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        protocol: 'http',
        livereload: true,
        open: true,
      }
    }
  },
});


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

grunt.registerTask('server', ['connect','watch']);

};
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make the livereload work but looking at your config and adding the hostname and livereload into the connect/server/options made the trick

Comment: No no no no no, `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` should NOT be added manually.  It will be auto-injected by the `grunt-contrib-connect` plugin, if done right.  You don't want that messing with a deployed version